# Can we compute predicted cumulative incidence after fitting a Cox model?

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

After fitting a Cox regression, we can compute the predicted survival curve S(t) e.g.
in R:

survfit(formula, newdata, ...)

where formula is a coxph object.
With the KM estimate, cumulative incidence is 1-S(t). Can we also do the same thing with the predicted S(t) from the Cox model to get the predicted cumulative incidence? I'm not sure if this is appropriate or whether it's better to use KM estimate for cumulative incidence.

Comment: The KM is a fully non-parametric method, whereas smoothed baseline hazard estimates exploit the proportional hazard assumption to avail prediction across a range of predictors. For categorical covariates, you can create KM curves for each combination of covariates if there is adequate subjects and failures in each group.

Comment: Thanks @AdamO. However, I wanted to know if what I suggested is valid?

Answer (score 1):

With at most one event possible per individual, the cumulative distribution of events over time, $F(t)$, is simply $F(t)=1-S(t)$ [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function). That has nothing to do with Kaplan-Meier versus Cox models. As that Wikipedia page says:

> Sometimes complementary cumulative distribution functions are called survival functions in general.

So "survival functions" can be defined in many contexts outside of what you might typically consider "survival analysis."

The choice between Kaplan-Meier and Cox-modeled survival/cumulative-distribution functions is thus based on what you want to display. Kaplan-Meier curves are closer to raw data, but if restricted to subsets of covariate values they lose power. Cox models employ all the data and can be used for survival-curve predictions at any set of covariate values, but you display a *predicted* survival or cumulative-distribution curve.

In R, the `plot.survfit()` function has a `fun` argument that leads to display of the cumulative distribution over time (with `fun="F"`) or other transformations of a survival function. In particular, if an individual can have multiple events you might choose `fun="cumhaz"` to plot the cumulative hazard of events.

Comment: Thank you. I would have thought that predicted survival or cumulative incidence would be preferable to account for other covariates like in all multiple regression models (assuming the model is correctly specified).

Comment: In the same way, I don't really get the idea of crude incidence. Surely a regression model that accounts for other effects to yield adjusted (predicted) incidence is preferable?

Comment: @user167591 a lot depends on the nature of the study. In a randomized trial the Kaplan-Meier curves are often preferred, as the randomization ideally controls for covariates and you don't need to make assumptions like proportional hazards to display the results. Predicted curves can be useful in observational studies insofar as the model is correct. Thus you also need to document the quality of the model carefully when you display predicted curves.

Comment: Thank you @EdM, that makes sense. Really sorry just one more thing, is it possible to get the incidence rate (not cumulative) after fitting the Cox model e.g. number per 1000 person years etc.? I know how to get the crude incidence rate or the adjusted one from a Poisson model using person time as offset, but assumed such an adjusted incidence rate could also be obtained after fitting in a Cox model?

Comment: Oh...I guess we get from the relationship: CI = 1 - exp(-IR x T)   ?

Comment: @user167591 a Cox model allows the baseline hazard to change arbitrarily over time, so there is not a constant incidence rate under any set of covariate values unless the baseline hazard is constant. If you assume a constant baseline hazard (exponential survival curve) then your prior comment seems OK, but then you might be better off fitting the exponential survival model to start with instead of the Cox model.

Comment: Thank you @EdM. May I please ask if I'm correct in thinking that under competing risks, the predicted cumulative incidence after fitting a cause-specific Cox model is biased? As such, is it reasonable under competing risks to derive hazard ratios from a cause-specific Cox model, BUT predicted cumulative incidence at a range of covariate settings from a Fine-Gray model?

Comment: @user167591 it's not clear why you think that. If anything, it's the other way around: the sum of event probabilities under Fine-Gray models can exceed 1, while the hazard ratios in Cox models can be harder to interpret than in Fine-Gray models. That issue is not directly on the topic of the current question, so if you want to pursue that further please post a new question on Cox versus Fine-Gray and include a link to any reference that might have led to what you said in your most recent comment.

Comment: Thank you @EdM. I have posted a new question as you suggested which can be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596055/cox-model-vs-fine-gray-hazard-ratios-predicted-cumulative-incidence-under-co